# Load a nested XML into multiple dataframes

Tags: xml, apache-spark-sql

I have been trying to load a nested XML into multiple dataframes. Consider the example below:

```
<Authors>
   <Author>
   <AuthorId>1</AuthorId>
   <AuthorName>Dickens</AuthorName>
   <Books>
   <AuthorId>1</AuthorId>
   <BookId>100</BookId>
   <BookName>ABC</BookName>
   </Books>
   </Author>

   <Author>
   <AuthorId>2</AuthorId>
   <AuthorName>Lovecraft</AuthorName>
   <Books>
   <AuthorId>2</AuthorId>
   <BookId>103</BookId>
   <BookName>WXY</BookName>
   </Books>
   </Author>
</Authors>
```

Now I want to have 2 dataframes, one for Author and one for Book.

Author Dataframe:

```
AuthorId   AuthorName
1           Dickens
2           Lovecraft
```

Book Dataframe

```
AuthorId   BookId   BookName
1          100      ABC
2          103      WXY
```

How to implement this in Scala? Also the name of columns is not known in advance.